# How do I go about resolving issue: Missing required keys (core) in modules/contrib/redirect/modules/redirect_404?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-modules

"The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later." When I went to clear cache in D8 and no further details. I have encountered a similar issue before on another drupal site and in my experience, the "Unexpected error" seems to be a general error message that Drupal gives, while there will likely be a more detailed message.

Thus, to further investigate the issue I enabled logging with  `$config['system.logging']['error_level'] = 'verbose';` in my settings.php.

Which produced the following upon refreshing the site:

`The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.</br></br><em class="placeholder">Drupal\Core\Extension\InfoParserException</em>: Missing required keys (core) in modules/contrib/redirect/modules/redirect_404/redirect_404.info.yml in <em class="placeholder">Drupal\Core\Extension InfoParserDynamic-&gt;parse()</em> (line <em class="placeholder">29</em> of <em class="placeholder">core/lib/Drupal/Core/Extension/InfoParserDynamic.php</em>). <pre class="backtrace">Drupal\Core\Extension\InfoParser-&gt;parse(&#039;modules/contrib/redirect/modules/redirect_404/redirect_404.info.yml&#039;) (Line: 552)`

I understand that sometimes issue come about when one does not clear the Drupal cache. As a result I have tried to flush all caches via the database by truncating the cache tables as the UI is unavailable. Also ran composer install; composer update but to no avail.

I would appreciate any solutions on how to address the issue at hand.

Thanks

Comment: Do you run the latest drupl core version ? (because https://pareview.sh/pareview/https-git.drupal.org-project-redirect.git-8.x-1.x/revisions/1488/view)

Comment: The site is running on running 8.7.11.

Comment: The error also appears when one runs ```drush updatedb```

Comment: ok.. sorry no clue. I don't know if it could help but still I would try to uninstall/reinstall the redirect module..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I saw this error as well, though on Drupal 8.7.6, after updating the Redirect module (and its submodules). I fixed it by adding `core: 8.x` to each module's .info.yml file, as was suggested in a [similar issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_toolbar/issues/3061832) for the Admin Toolbar module.

I then updated Drupal core to version 8.1.1, at which point I had to remove that line – `The 'core_version_requirement' constraint (^8.7.7 || ^9) requires the 'core' key not be set` – so that may be a temporary measure.

(As an aside, you mentioned clearing cache through the UI and the database, but you can also clear your cache using Drush: https://drushcommands.com/drush-8x/cache/cache-rebuild/)

Comment: Perfect answer @Kurt ! Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Kurt, this was exactly what I needed! I had the same issue but with the token and webform module. Good lord the webform one had sooo many submodules.